# Lightswitch with data in SQL Azure: Your session may have timed out. Please restart the application

Tags: azure-sql-database, visual-studio-lightswitch

I built a Lightswitch app to edit my SQL Azure data. If I open the app and don't use it for a while, when I try to to use it again I get the error:

> User does not have access to the invoked operation.  Your session may
>   have timed out.  Please restart the application.

It seems that the connection was closed because it was not being used and I need to create a new connection.
What can I change to avoid getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved in Lightswitch 2012.
If the user got disconnected for lack of activity Lightswitch now gratefully asks for a login again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on Lightswitch, but in SQL Azure a connection can be forcibly closed by the host. You need to implement some retry logic when getting the connection.

Some useful links

[Using the Transient Fault Handling Application Block with SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680899%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

[Retry Logic for Transient Failures in SQL Azure](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4235.retry-logic-for-transient-failures-in-sql-azure.aspx)